# Returning True if the number of opening and closing parentheses are the same

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that will return true if the number of opening and closing parentheses in a string are equal. If they're not, I need it to return false. Currently this is not working for all strings. For example, `paren_parity('p)(()ld))()(eog((h)k(j(m()(nc)fab)i)',)` returns true as it should but `paren_parity('d)p))mk)bc))j((eif(()ln)o)h((ag',)` is returning True even though the number of open and closed parentheses are not the same.

```
def paren_parity(z):
  stack = []
  pushChars, popChars = "<({[", ">)}]"
  for c in z :
if c in pushChars :
  stack.append(c)
elif c in popChars :
  if not len(stack) :
    return False
  else :
    stackTop = stack.pop()
    balancingBracket = pushChars[popChars.index(c)]
    if stackTop != balancingBracket:
      return False
else :
  return True
return not len(stack)
```

Comment: Can't you just `.count('(')` and `.count(')')` and see if they are equal?  Or do you actually need to validate that each open paren has a corresponding closing paren?

Comment: @mgilson I haven't tried that, would you be able to give an example? I am not sure how this would be applied

Comment: Add to one of 2 separate fields for each paren found.  If closed is ever greater than open, it is an error.  At the end, if the two are not equal, it is an error.

Comment: As a lambda function, it'd look like this: `lambda z: z.count('(') == z.count(')')`

Answer (score 2):

You've got a couple choices.  The first is really easy, just count the number of opening parens and closing and check for equality:

```
def paren_parity(z):
    return z.count('(') == z.count(')')
```

But, this will pass strings like `'))))(((('` which you might not want.  Otherwise, you can keep a count of the number of opened parens as you walk over the string.  If the count ever goes negative, then return `False`:

```
def paren_parity(z):
    open_count = 0
    for c in z:
        if c == '(':
            open_count += 1
        if c == ')':
            open_count -= 1
            if open_count < 0:
                return False
    return open_count == 0
```

Of course, this still doesn't actually work for parsing programming language text because it'll fail for things like `a = 5 * ('yeah!)')` (since I have a parenthesis embedded in a string).  However, I'm going to assume that isn't an issue for your current problem ;-).

Comment: Thank you very much @mgilson, the first solution will work perfectly and was MUCH more simple than I thought it was going to be

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem:

```
else :
  return True
```

If you encounter something that isn't a parenthesis, you always return `True`. So `d(` will return `True` as soon as you hit the `d`.

You can fix it by just removing the those lines.

Answer (score -1):

This is easily resolved with a tail recursive function, including determining if there is a 'mismatch'.

```
def paren_parity(z, opening=0):
  if len(z) == 0:
    return opening == 0
  head, *tail = z
  if head == "(":
    opening = opening + 1
  elif head == ")":
    if opening == 0:
      return False
    opening = opening - 1
  return paren_parity(tail, opening)
```

`opening` acts as the stack you're pushing and popping from. Since you don't care as to the value, just whether it's a push or pop, holding an integer is enough.

Comment: I don't think your recursion really buys you much here.  In languages with tail recursion optimization, the recursion optimization would probably be optimized out, but in python, you're likely to run into a recursion error as soon as the strings get long.

Comment: Fair enough: I forgot that Python didn't optimize tail recursion away.